# Auto-generate graphql resolver signatures

Tags: typescript, graphql

I have the following GraphQL Schema:

```
type User {
  id: ID
  name: String
}

type Mutation {
  createUser(name: String): User
}
```

And I want to create the signature and the resolver in typescript

```
type createUser = (name: string) => User; // <- signature

const createUserResolver: createUser = (name) => {} as User; // <- resolver
```

But if I define the `createUser` signature by hand and then the schema changes, I will need to update the signature.

Is there any way to auto-generate the signature when the schema changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`typescript-resolvers` plugin](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-resolvers) of [GraphQL Code Generator](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs).

Example config:

```
schema: ./graphql/**/.graphql
generates:
  ./src/resolvers-types.ts:
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-resolvers
```

Run codegen and then you can import a `Resolvers` type to use with your resolver map:

```
import { Resolvers } from './resolvers-types';

export const resolvers: Resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    createUser: (root, args, context) => {
      // args type will be inferred based on your type definitions
    },
  }
};
```

If you need to extract an individual signature, you can do this: `Resolvers['Mutation']['createUser']`